# AngularJS Karma-Jasmine get into $q.when().finally(function () {}); in unit test

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine, angular-promise

```
angular.module('some-module').service('some-service', [
'a_workflow',
'b_api',
function(Workflow, Api) {
    this.prepareToEnterFlow = function(forward, flowContext, pageContext, transitionData, callback) {
        flowContext.data = transitionData.data;
        $q.when(flowContext.data.container).finally(function() {
             var value = 'I am testing';
             console.log(value);
             $q.when(flowContext.data.container.cookies).finally(function() {

             });
        });
    }
}
```

]);

How can i see that "I am testing" in my unit test? Do i need to mock anything to get there?

Comment: By spying on console.log (if it's your real code). Nested promises are themselves an antipattern that can make promises harder to test. Always return and chain promises. `finally` isn't a good place for that because it doesn't allow chaining.

Comment: Hi estus, thx for the reply, but is there a way i can make it happen? I have seen lots of example about thenable but nothing about when().finally

Comment: This doesn't seem to be real code ($q.when() is a noop), so it's unclear why it's there. As for spying, it's https://jasmine.github.io/2.9/introduction#section-Spies